# How can I initial my function in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a beginner of AS3. I want to create a simple bouncing ball in a space limited in the canvas of 400*450. But it cannot work when I publish it. Anyone can help me figure this out?
PS: Is there any nice website can help me learn more things about AS3?

Here is my code:

```
function ballmoving(evt:Event = null):void 
{
    var vel_x = 5;
    var vel_y = 6;
    ball.x = -20;
    ball.y = 280;

    ball.x += vel_x;
    ball.y += vel_y;    
    if (ball.x > stage.stageWidth - ball.width / 2 || ball.x < 0 + ball.width /2)
    {
        vel_x *= -1;
    }
    else if (ball.y > 280 || ball.y < 0 + ball.height /2)
    {
        vel_y *= -1;
    }
}

ballmoving();

RecycleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ball.x = -20;
    ball.y = 280;
    ballmoving();
}
```

Comment: I've already set the ball as a movieclip in adobe flash cs6, so I haven't defined it again in coding. There is no alert for my code. But the ball just cannot move

Comment: Everytime the `ballmoving` function is called the ball is set to `-20,280` then moved by `5,6`, which puts it at `-15,286`. So it never moves.

Comment: Thx for your reply, Barış. Actually I just tried remove the setting    -20,280, and there is a same default position in flash canvas. But it still cannot move.

Comment: See if my answer helps. If you set the ball positon in ballmoving or the reset function it won't move anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like :

```
var vel_x = 5;
var vel_y = 6;

function ballmoving(evt:Event = null):void 
{

    ball.x += vel_x;
    ball.y += vel_y;    
    if (ball.x > stage.stageWidth - ball.width / 2 || ball.x < ball.width /2)
    {
        vel_x *= -1;
    }

    if (ball.y > 280 || ball.y < ball.height /2)
    {
        vel_y *= -1;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballmoving);
RecycleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ball.x = -20;
    ball.y = 280;
}
```

Comment: You will most likely want to attach the `ballmoving` function to the `ENTER_FRAME` event: `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ballmoving);`

Comment: Edited so it uses ENTER_FRAME and the mouse click resets the ball.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. It can move by only clicking the button everytime. What I want is letting the ball automatically bounce inside the canvas. I've tried to add an eventlistener to activate it, and the ball is moving, but another problem happened as the ball cannot move in the right way. So I guess I need to modify the function.

Comment: If you want it to move only by clicking then remove the enter frame handler and just call `ballmoving` inside the `reset` function. You might also need to remove the else and just do 2 if statements those conditions can both apply at the corners.